# How can I solve a mapping in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, yaml

I have a Store entity and I want to have a one to many relationship where for each Store I can select a ShippingMethod. I do the mapping with YAML.

The shippingMethod attribute is already added to the model. It only remains to solve a mapping

```
EasyCommerce\StorePlugin\Entity\Store:
    type: mappedSuperclass
    table: easycommerce_store
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        //fields
    manyToOne:
        shippingMethod:
            targetEntity: Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShippingMethodInterface;
            joinColumn:
                shipping_method_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

Error Message:

```
In MappingException.php line 772:
                                                                                                                                                     
  The target-entity Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShippingMethodInterface; cannot be found in 'EasyCommerce\StorePlugin\Entity\Store#shippingMethod'.
```

Comment: are the namespace defined correctly and includes `Sylius\Component\Core\Model\` ?

Comment: also could you try removing that semicolon...

Comment: the targetEntity cannot be an Interface. It has to be an actual class, with an actual table.